# Angular $compile outside modules

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with AngularJS compile service. I am working out of angular but I can not compile my template, (I either try with a controller but I do not know why it does not work).

Due to specific development I can not use directives nor controllers.

Here is a Plunker of my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/u9nfopTiikxjXmwzOgqh?p=preview

PS: This is a simple example, but I really need the compile service ($interpolate does not feet my needs)

Comment: I try to understand the code you posted, maybe Im noob but how do you want to represent `{{bar}}` in HTML without controller, hmmm. Maybe its new angular version

Comment: @MaximShoustin Actually interpolation is made against scope not a controller. Look at plnkr in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It works! Just call `scope.$apply()`. Btw. if you be calling `result.html()` you are appending the copy of `html` that is not bound any more to the `scope`. If you just append `result`, the magic happens... Look at the [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnuLFJLdW7qYAtOTOhCd?p=preview).

Comment: yep, thought about `apply` after DOM manipualtion but never used interpolation,

Comment: I run in a second issue xD, maybe you can tell me how to deal with this http://plnkr.co/edit/l49f0gikYVYUwawJ2hmq?p=info

Comment: @IxDay you still appended copy of html and using `$http` will automatically call `$scope.$apply()`. [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/8ppvpSJpmc43h4jIMiDW?p=preview).