# How to use AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC ajax-loaded popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am just starting with AngularJS, and I want to integrate it into existing ASP.NET MVC application.

I created simple angular HelloWorld app, that I return in a simple view rendered by a controller action:

```
<div ng-app="HelloNg">
    <h1> Hello {{1+1}} you</h1>
</div>
```

This worked great - I could see angular expression evaluated properly.

However in our app, the data is often shown in ajax-loaded popups. So bascially the JavaScript makes request to  MVC controller, the view gets renderred and is sent back. Then JavaScript stuffs it into a prepared div and shows that div as a popup.

In that case, the angular expression is not processed and `{{1 + 1}}` is rendered verbatim to the screen. The main page that hosts the popup is standard ASP.NET page - it does not use angular at all, it does however import angular scripts.

From what I understand I should use angular $compile service to let angular know about it - however I am not sure how to set the $scope variable.

Could anybody point me in the right direction? In most of the samples I could see $compile service being used within angular controller or directive, but in my case I am trying to do it from outside of the angular world.

The main page is massive, and I do not want to convert it to angular at this point - so having the popup use angular only would work great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding some related questions, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383294/angular-compile-outside-modules), I was able to figure it out:

```
// Here data is HTML returned from ajax

angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$compile', '$rootScope', 
  function (compile, rootScope) {
    var scope = rootScope.$new();
     var result  = compile(data)(scope);            
     scope.$apply();             
     data = result;

     // Here data is same HTML but now it is recognized by angular  
     ... render it to page here ...
   }
]);
```

It probably can be done much better but this seems to work for me all - all angular markup is processed when popup shows - and all bindings seem to work as well.